# Sails.js routes returns JSON response not error page if view page is not available

Tags: sails.js

Problem : I have an entry in sails routes.js like -

```
'/agent-details': { view: 'agents/agent-details' }
```

But i don't have this file available in view/agents folder.

While accessing **/agent-details** url it returns JSON response

```
    {
      "message": "Could not render view \"agents/agent-details\".  Tried locating view file @ \"/Users/user/ckr/sails/proj/views/agents/agent-details\". Layout configured as \"layouts/public\", so tried using layout @ \"/Users/user/ckr/sails/proj/views/layouts/public\")",
      "code": "E_VIEW_FAILED",
      "status": 500,
      "view": {
        "name": "agents/agent-details",
        "root": "/Users/user/ckr/sails/proj/views",
        "defaultEngine": "ejs",
        "ext": ".ejs"
      }
    }
```

but I want response 500.ejs/404.ejs to be returned.

Hope i'll get some solution for this.
Thank You !!!

Comment: You don't have layout file which is added to every view by default.

Comment: i have layout file, error files in views folder - 403.ejs, 404.ejs, 500.ejs but if requested file is not available its not returning error files - returning JSON

Comment: Because its template engine error. They are always json. Only Model and controller errors display custom error pages.

Comment: I do agree but how to configure to return error files if we mention view in routes and that view is not available.

Comment: Error pages are just for unexpected error. This error is your fault and it should be caught while development. Why would you do that? Doing errors on purpose ?

Comment: My scenario is - I have 1000+ files in view folder and each files is associated with an url, Now if some file is missing from view it's returning JSON response and its not looking good on website instead of JSON response i want to return an error page so it'll look good on website. Now if urls is associated with any action it'll return error page but its not associated with any controller's action and assigned directly in routes.js - Now how ll i get error page is my concern -- any idea?

Comment: Can't you use static files? Just put them in assets.

Comment: can you please explain how?

Comment: You can put html files directly in assets. But they will not have same layout. http://sailsjs.org/documentation/concepts/assets

Comment: No i want with default layout.

Comment: I found problem - if i rename or delete file and don't lift sails then its happening once you lift sails its returning 404.ejs page. :) But ideally that time also it should return 404.ejs page.. anyways thanks ...